# Clone object property is automatically referenced?

Tags: files, tokens

I use D6 with filefield, imagefield, imagefield_paths, token, cck. I create a new content type with two imagefields with a default image.

Now every time I test it http://pastebin.com/EXf2R5dA. In fact, token uses drupal_clone then node_view to generates tokens without touching the original object. But in this case it changes.

Do anyone knows what happens? $items in the patch is an array (and is genenated in content_token_values() in cck/includes/content.token.inc).

Comment: There is a bug with imagefield_paths and the patch http://drupal.org/node/1027140#comment-4632594 fixes it. However I still don't know why drupal_clone() (in content_token_values()) does not copy $node->field_blabla which is an array.